# How to associate a request with a HttpSession in a Java EE application, based on request payload?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httpsession

I have a Java EE application that receives requests over http/s. The requests do not contain any cookies or jsessionid request parameters.

In the request payload I can find a string "sessionid" that should allow me to associate that request to an HttpSession. I've managed to implement a mechanism that stores a map of sessions in memory, but that's not (easily) scalable in a cluster environment.

The standard Java EE mechanism for associating requests to HttpSessions is based on cookies or URL rewriting, which are not available for me, since I don't control the 3-rd party that sends the requests. Also, the HttpServletRequest object does not have a setSession() method.

Is there a straightforward way to associate requests to HttpSessions, without relying on a particular Java EE server or on some distributed cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few statements:

- The 3rd party client does not conform to the HTTP spec, and that's not your problem
- If you need a custom mechanism, you should implement all of it. That is, do not rely on HttpSession - make a `Map<String, Object>` for each sessionId and support it yourelf
- Any other solution would require plugging your code into the container (for tomcat thay might be a Valve), but there is no standard solution.

Comment: I know that HttpServletRequest has a getSession. It doesn't have a setSession.

Comment: The first point hits the nail straight on the head. Fix the client, or tell the responsible to fix it.

Comment: @VictorIonescu sorry, I misread it. Removed that point. The others still remain.

Answer (score 0):

I've been on that road before and it was a dead end. You really need to opt other mechanism than `HttpSession`
It could be as simple as a unique id for each session (which should be stored in database rather than in memory) or something more sophisticated.
Following links might help you

- [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)
- [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [Google's ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) (although deprecated by google, its a good architecture to study)

But yes, changing the mechanism *does* mean that the third-party has to conform to it.